# Why is this a bad request react native axios put request

Tags: javascript, api, react-native, axios

Why is this request a bad request, I have sent the same request in postman, using raw data, and header content-type applications/json and it works.
But in my axios request, I get bad request

```
const update = dispatch => {

  return async (name, email, phone, picture, Age, Blood, Gender, Height, Weight, id) => {
    const data = new FormData();

    data.append('name', name);
    data.append('email', email);
    data.append('phone', phone);
    data.append('Age', Age);
    data.append('Blood', Blood);
    data.append('Gender', Gender);
    data.append('Height', Height);
    data.append('Weight', Weight);
    data.append("picture", {
      type: 'image/jpg',
      uri: picture,
      name: 'profilepic.jpg'
    });
    const config = {
      method: 'put',
      url: `http://c256474d.ngrok.io/api/userregister/24`,
      data: data,
      headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' }

    }


    await axios(config)
    navigate('UserAccount')
  }
}
```

This is the server side code, this works when tested with postman. It doesn't work when send with form-data, but works when the body is raw and header of application/json

```
        public function update(Request $request, $id)
      {
       // dd($request->all());
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email' => 'string|email|max:255',
        'phone' => 'string|min:6',
        'Age' => 'string',
        'Blood' => 'string',
        'Gender' => 'string',
        'Height' => 'string',
        'Weight' => 'string',
        'record' => 'string'
    ]);

    if($validator->fails()){
            return response()->json($validator->errors()->toJson(), 400);
    }

    $doc = User::find($id);

    if($request->hasFile('picture')){
        // Get filename with the extension
        $filenameWithExt = $request->file('picture')->getClientOriginalName();
        // Get just filename
        $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        // Get just ext
        $extension = $request->file('picture')->getClientOriginalExtension();
        // Filename to store
        $fileNameToStore= $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
        // Upload Image
        $path = $request->file('picture')->storeAs('public/images', $fileNameToStore);
    } else {
        $fileNameToStore = 'noimage.jpg';
    }

    $doc->name = $request->input('name');
      $doc->email = $request->input('email');
      $doc->phone = $request->input('phone');
      if($request->hasFile('picture')){
        $doc->picture = $fileNameToStore;
        }



       $doc->save();

    return response()->json([
        'message' => 'Success',

    ]);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can't *know* why the server thinks the data is bad because you haven't shared the server-side code that makes that determination.

It's a fairly reasonable bet that including `'content-type': 'application/json'` in the headers and then **not sending JSON** in the body isn't helping though.

`FormData` objects are used to generate `multipart/form-data` request bodies, not `application/json`.

If you want to send JSON then you need to generate JSON:

```
const data = {
  name: name,
  email: email,
  phone: phone,
  Age: Age,
  Blood: Blood,
  Gender: Gender,
  Height: Height,
  Weight: Weight,
  picture: {
    type: "image/jpg",
    uri: picture,
    name: "profilepic.jpg"
  }
};
const config = {
  method: "put",
  url: `http://c256474d.ngrok.io/api/userregister/24`,
  data: JSON.stringify(data),
  headers: { "content-type": "application/json" }
};
```

Comment: It still returns 400 Bad request

Comment: You can check the server side code in my question, I have included it in the question

Answer (score 0):

Change your header to

```
{ headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' } }
```

You are not sending JSON Data.

Comment: You omitted the `boundary` parameter. Let underlying XHR object figure out the content type by virtue of being passed `FormData`, don't be explicit. Also, since the API is expecting JSON, that won't really help.